# Entity Framework order by after ThenInclude()

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, automapper

I am returning an entity:

```
var entity = _context.Note
            .Include(b => b.Flag)
            .Include(b => b.Status)
            .ThenInclude(b => b.Nav)
            .ThenInclude(bc => bc.Descr)
            .Include(b => b.File)
            .ThenInclude(b => b.TDom)
            .ThenInclude(b => b.LanguageNavigation)
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id== id);
```

I want to order `TDom` by `Date` but I can't figure out how do I select it?

My mapper.cs

```
CreateMap<Note, NoteViewDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EndDate, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ViewEnddateResolver, DateTime?>(src => src.Enddate))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Pid))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<Tpdomainvalue, IdName>(src.Status)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Descriptions,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<ICollection<TDom>, List<NoteViewDto>>(src.TDom))

                );
```

Comment: Note that you *either* use `Include` *or* project to a DTO using AutoMapper. Projection ignores `Include` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Update your mapping call to:

```
CreateMap<Note, NoteViewDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EndDate, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ViewEnddateResolver, DateTime?>(src => src.Enddate))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Pid))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<Tpdomainvalue, IdName>(src.Status)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Descriptions, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<ICollection<TDom>, List<NoteViewDto>>(src.TDom.OrderBy(e => e.Date))));
```